# Set the permission for custom action

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I created the **View ribbon custom action** in SharePoint designer, now I want to set the **permission** for that. just **one user can use this action**.

Do you have advice for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating/editing the custom action in SPD you will find “Rights mask” under advanced custom action options. Here you can set rights on custom actions.

If you set the rights mask to include the Edit Item permission then only someone who has EditItem permission to that web site will see the entry.  Its based off the permissions that you have in the context where the item is visible.

For more detailed information, refer to the following article:

http://techwirenews.com/2012/03/10/setting-rights-for-custom-actions-using-sharepoint-designer-2010-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/